# fadeToggle on a div with divs inside doesn't work in IE as expected

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fade

I have this setup:

```
<div class="fadetoggle">
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

And this code:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  $(".fadetoggle").fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

In all modern browser I tested it so far it works but in IE8 the div "fadetoggle" just shows/hide. If I use fadeToggle on only a div without children it works in IE8.

How comes? And is there a way to make fadeToggle in IE with my setup working?

Comment: can you give me a fiddle

Comment: here's the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/QT43M. As "expected" this short version of the code is working correct in IE8. So I guess there must be problem with my code where I use it with some more properties around it. Didn't expect that but I'll report back as soon as I know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's what was happening:

1. IE doesn't like fades on fixed elements. So I "wrapped" them up in a div and got it to work with this:

   $("div-wrapper").children().fadeToggle();
2. On another div inside a "group-div" I had declared position:relative & float:right at the same time in the css. Of course this is redundant anyways and so it was irretating IE I guess.

So I just removed position:relative and everything works fine now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
check this not sure frnd

   $(".button").click(function () {
if($(fadetoggle).is(":visible"))//IE8 always evaluates to true.
     $(fadetoggle).hide();
else
     $(fadetoggle).show();
});
```

chage this to satisfy your needs

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to still find a solution. But yes, of course your code works, thanks! But the same: The div just shows/hide. I am now having a deeper look at my code where I am using this constellation. I report back as soon as I found a solution.